# remove outer label of checkbox in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using ruby on my project . I need custom style for check boxes.

please find below code

```
<%= f.input :category_ids, :as => :check_boxes do %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.order(:name), :id, :name do |b|
    b.label { b.check_box + b.text }
  end %>
<% end %>
```

Using above code Im getting out like

```
<label for="property_space_amenities_space_amenities_2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="property[space_amenities][space_amenities][]" id="property_space_amenities_space_amenities_2">Internet connectivity
</label>
```

form this im not able give custom style for this

i want output like below

```
<label class="control-label" for="user_login">Login</label>
<input class="form-control" id="user_login" name="user[login]" type="text" />
```

Please help me in this

Comment: Where does the `f.input` method come from? It is not a Rails method. Do you use some form builder gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [rails doc](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes), you can have separated label and checkbox by not using the "do" block.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.order(:name), :id, :name %>
```

btw, this is only for rails >= 4.0.2, maybe you can remove your rails 3 tag.

Comment: I'm getting same result no change

Comment: Have u removed the outer "f.input" ?

Comment: Out put is coming like below

<label for="property_space_amenities_2"><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="property[space_amenities][]" id="property_space_amenities_2"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="property_space_amenities_2">Internet connectivity</label></label>

Comment: Isn't this what you needed in your question ?

Comment: actually i need out put like

<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="property[space_amenities][]" id="property_space_amenities_2"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="property_space_amenities_2">Internet connectivity</label>

Comment: and one more thing check value is not getting check box but its working when im using f.association